# Topologies on the collection of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $\mathfrak S$ be the collection of all $\sigma$-algebras on $X$.

That is, a typical element $\mathscr S\in\mathfrak S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. For example, $\{\varnothing, X\}\in\mathfrak S$; if $A$ is a non-empty proper subset of $X$, then $\{\varnothing,A,A^{\mathsf c},X\}\in\mathfrak S$; and if $X$ is a topological space and $\mathscr B(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathscr B(X)\in\mathfrak S$; and so forth.

**Question:** *Is there a “natural” way of endowing $\mathfrak S$ with a topology?*

Any reference or comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: About 10 to 12 years ago I came across some papers endowing this collection with a metric. A few years afterwards I posted a list of the papers I knew about in this [10 March 2007 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5565468), and the list was later copied into the math overflow question [Is the Hausdorff metric on sub-$\sigma$-fields separable?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79869/is-the-hausdorff-metric-on-sub-sigma-fields-separable). (I'm giving a link to my sci.math post because for some reason the link to it in the math overflow post crashed by browser.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you very much for the detailed references. I will check them out!